# Intellectual who supports a political party in return for benefits

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the right single word for an intellectual (often a journalist) who is not a member of a political party, but justifies the party's causes to the general public and secretly takes benefit from them in return?

Comment: Related: There's the word _lobbyist_, referring to those who "attempt to influence legislators on behalf of a particular interest." However, a lobbyist isn't generally a journalist, and not all of them take secret benefits, either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A **[shill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shill)** is a tout or promoter, with the connotation of figure who endorses a product or service— or candidate or party— on a supposedly independent basis, when in fact he or she is in the service of the person or organization benefiting from the endorsement.

Comment: +1. I think this is the only answer so far which captures the dishonest aspect requested by the OP. "*secretly* takes benefit".

Answer (score 2):

A related phrase is  *[fellow traveller](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fellow_traveller)*,“One who sympathizes with the aims or beliefs of an organization, without belonging to it; most often applied to a Communist sympathizer”.  Technically, the phrase applies fairly well in the current context, except that people are unlikely to automatically suppose a fellow traveller is an intellectual or a journalist or secretly receives benefits.

Depending on context, also consider nouns *[collaborator](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/collaborator#Noun)* and *[quisling](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quisling#Noun)*, and phrase *[tame journalist](http://blog.escherman.com/2008/09/09/how-to-test-your-media-pitch-with-a-tame-journalist/)*.

Comment: So why note use *sympathiser*

Answer (score 2):

> **partisan** (noun) an adherent or supporter of a person, group, party,
>   or cause, especially a person who shows a biased, emotional
>   allegiance. ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/partisan))

Answer (score 2):

Two words not previously suggested are *hack* and *hireling*. According to R. L. Chapman and B.A. Kipfer, *Dictionary of American Slang*, Third Edition (1995):

> **hack 8 n** (also ) *by 1810* A professional, usu freelance, writer who works to order[.] This sense belongs to hack [definition 1, meaning "A taxicab"], reflecting the notion that such a writer was for hire like a horse, ...

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) offers this definition:

> **hack** *n.* [short for *hack*ney] **3 a :** a person who works solely for mercenary reasons : hireling

As for *hireling*, the *Eleventh Collegiate* says this:

> **hireling n :** a person who serves for hire esp. for purely mercenary motives

Other options that might suit the situation are *apologist*, *mouthpiece*, *mercenary*, and *hired gun*.

Comment: I like the word _apologist_. But the word _shill_ serves my present purpose best.